# cassandra 3.0.0.8 memtable flush is not happening

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

i am using cassandra 3.0.0.8 on centos i got the below error in the logs after that metable flushes are not happening

```
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:7735] 2017-01-18 23:00:02,101 CassandraDaemon.java:201 - Exception in thread Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:7735,5,RMI Runtime]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:39) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Please elaborate your code and format it to get better help and attention.

Comment: Can you try to upgrade to higher version of Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to data corruption.

Try to run repair on the node.
If it doesn't help, try to run rebuild on the node.

Does it happens on 1 node or all nodes in the cluster?